# Is there any way to optimized my FFmpeg commands for streaming so it doesn’t overwhelm my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying, from a Raspberry Pi, to stream a video flux to a remote web server (it's for an owl birdhouse).

So, the Raspberry Pi, is set up, and my export command line is :

```
libcamera-vid -t 0 -o - | ffmpeg -i - -f mpegts -preset slow - codec:a libfdk_aac -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p udp://x.x.x.x:xxxx
```

On the receiving server, here is the ffmpeg command :

```
ffmpeg -i udp://x.x.x.x:xxxx -s 640x480   -c:v libx264 -strftime 1 -hls_segment_filename 'file-%Y%m%d_%H-%M-%S.ts'  -use_localtime 1 mystream.m3u8
```

The problem is the CPU of my server is 100%, and I get buffering. I've tried multiple ffmpeg parameters, lowered the resolution to what I believe is the minimum, and yet, still buffering and high CPU.

Is there a way with ffmpeg to minimize the work on the server side?

I don't need audio, don't really care for good quality even if the higher the better.

Comment: Have you confirmed it is ffmpeg using most of the CPU? What's the network that you're streaming this over?

Comment: Doesn’t the Raspberry Pi have some built-in video encoder hardware? Try to utilize that. _libx264_ is purely software. Also, consider tuning the parameters, which you are currently not doing at all.

Comment: @music2myear Yes, I confirmed 100% it is ffmpeg using most of the CPU. What do you mean "What's the network" ? It's streamed from my house to my OVH server, so over the internet.

Comment: @DanielB I'll look into the hardware built-in encoder. The goal would be to encode before sending, so the receiver wouldn't have to do it ?
I'm a bit lost on which parameter should be customized. Wich parameter are needed, and which are not ?